# VMBox fatal error during installation (Log error included)

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I've been trying to install vmbox 5.2.8. for windows 10 home for about a week now.
I have been running as admin and the error occurs when the installation phase gets to 'copying new files' then closes and says fatal error occurred.
As such I enabled MSI logging to find the error and it seems these lines make the issue clear,

The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2888. The arguments are: TextStyle, , 
Action ended 12:41:43: VBoxFatalErrorDlg. Return value 2.
Action ended 12:41:43: INSTALL. Return value 3

CustomAction MsiInstallDrivers returned actual error code 1603 (note this may not be 100% accurate if translation happened inside sandbox)
MSI (s) (A8:38) [12:41:40:264]: Closing MSIHANDLE (107) of type 790536 for thread 10448
Action ended 12:41:40: InstallFinalize. Return value 3.

I am not sure about the solution to these problems. 
I will leave a full link to the log below,

https://www.dropbox.com/s/m67j73ejxegvqms/MSI58188.LOG?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in this [link](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/insufficient-system-resources-exist-complete-requested-service), you can follow these steps:

Start by opening the File Explorer.
Now, navigate to the following path,

```
C:\Users\
```

Select the folder for your User Account. Right click on it and click on Properties. Navigate to the tab labeled as Security.

Now click on Advanced.

On the bottom of the window, check the box that says, *Replace all child object permissions with inheritable permissions from this object*.

Click OK. Reboot your computer for the changes to take effect.

Right-Click the Virtual Box installer -> Run as Administrator.

This time the Virtual Box will be installed successfully.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Link-only answers are generally [frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/204922) on Stack Overflow. In time it is possible for links to atrophy and become unavailable, meaning that your answer is useless to users in the future. It would be best if you could provide the general details of your answer in your actual post, citing your link as a reference